# Append 24 Hour Time format with Sybase date format

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to append/convert time in 24hour format `(20:20)` with `"01/01/1900"` . I am using `sybase` database . I need to store it in sybase database(datetime field) like this  `"01/01/1900 20:20:00"` . The `24 hour time format` is entered by user . I would like to append it to this date `"01/01/1900"` . While retrieving from database i would also like to convert the date time field to time field in `24 hour format` Should i use Gregorian Calendar / should i convert the string into date time format . How can i achieve this . Looking for suggestions

Comment: In Javascript or in Java?  You've mistakenly tagged it with both.

Comment: Java,sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I am asking for Suggestions :) Thanks for commenting !

Comment: I think the method you want might be `LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate date, LocalTime time)` but it's a little hard to tell from your question.  I recommend staying away from `GregorianCalendar`.

Answer (score 1):

## Use objects, not strings

Your JDBC driver’s job is to translate between Java objects and the database’s own data format.

On the Java side, avoid the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` and `Calendar`. They are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The `LocalTime` class is for a time-of-day value without date and without time zone.

Your input string happens to comply with standard ISO 8601 formats. The java.time classes use these standard formats by default. So no need to specify a parsing format.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "20:21" );
```

Similarly, `LocalDate` for date-only format.

To get the current date requires a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z );
```

In the case of this Question, we want a hard-coded date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1900 , Month.JANUARY , 1 );
```

Put those pieces together and assign their intended time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 016-12-17T20:21-05:00[America/Montreal]

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/D2Jrf6).

Pass to your database via JDBC through `PreparedStatement::setObject`.

```
myPS.setObject( … , zdt );
```

If your driver does not yet support JDBC 4.2, fall back to using the old java.sql types with your driver. Look to new methods added to the old classes for conversion.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( zdt.toInstant() );
myPS.setTimestamp( … , ts );
```

These issues have been handled in many other Questions and Answers. Search Stack Overflow for much more discussion and more examples.